# 1 - form and smooth vector fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

This question was asked in my mid term  of smooth manifolds and I couldn't solve it in exam time. I tried it again at home and I think I need help.

> Question:  Let w be a 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If X and Y are smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that dw(X,Y) = X(w(Y))-Y(w(X)) - w([X,Y]).

1-form is equivalent to saying linear functional. But I am not able to make any progress due as I am not sure which result should I use.

Can you please help me with this proof  by giving a few hints?

Thanks!

Comment: A $1$-form is not a linear functional, so better review your definition.

Comment: @Thorgott Well , wikipedia also has the same definition :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form

Comment: @Avenger the restriction to each fiber is a linear functional. A $1$-form itself is not a linear functional, it is a section of the dual tangent bundle.

Comment: It would be good to add your definition of the exterior derivative to the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$X = \sum_i a_i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$,
$Y = \sum_j b_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ so that
$[X,Y] = \sum_{k=1}^n (\sum_i a_i \frac{\partial b_k}{\partial x_i} - b_i \frac{\partial a_k}{\partial x_i}) \frac{ \partial }{\partial x_k}$.

Let $w = \sum f_i dx^i$ so that $dw = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} dx^j \wedge dx^i$. Recall that $X$ acts on functions $f$ via $Xf(p) = \sum a_i(p) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (p)$.

We have $w(Y) = \sum_j f_j \cdot b_j$ and $w(X) = \sum_i f_i \cdot a_i$ so that

$\frac{\partial w(Y)}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} b_j + f_j \cdot \frac{\partial b_j}{\partial x_i} $

and

$\frac{\partial w(X)}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i,j} \frac{ \partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \cdot a_i + f_i \cdot \frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}.$

Now the left-hand side gives

\begin{align*}
  dw(X,Y) = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} dx^j \wedge dx^i (X,Y) \\
  =  \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} (p) \cdot (a_jb_i - a_ib_j)(p)
  \end{align*}

and the right-hand side $X(w(Y)) - Y(w(X)) - w([X,Y])$ gives

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(p) \frac{\partial w(Y)}{\partial x_i}(p) - \sum_{j=1}^n b_j (p) \frac{\partial w(X)}{\partial x_j} - \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(p) \cdot ( \sum_i a_i \frac{\partial b_k}{\partial x_i} - b_i \frac{\partial a_k}{\partial x_i})(p) = ... $$
$$...=  \sum_{i,j}^n a_i \cdot ( \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} b_j + f_j \cdot \frac{\partial b_j}{\partial x_i}) - \sum_{i,j} b_j \cdot ( \frac{ \partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \cdot a_i + f_i \cdot \frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}) - \sum_{k=1}^n f_k \cdot (\sum_i a_i \frac{\partial b_k}{\partial x_i} - b_i \frac{\partial a_k}{\partial x_i})$$
$$ = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} (p) \cdot (a_jb_i - a_ib_j)(p) $$

which is the left-hand side above.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: I have asked many other questions in Manifolds. Can you please have a look at some of them too.  No-one is answering them. I shall be really grateful.

Comment: How does $w=\sum f_idx_i$ will imply that  $dw= \sum_{i,j}∂f_i/∂x_j (dx^j∧dx^i)$. Can  you please write down the definition you are using or supply a proof. I am struck on this.